# How do I limit the number of choices from an checkbox on jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-plugins

How do I get the count of the selected checkboxes from jenkinsfile?
I need in case of more than 4 choises the job stop ou execute a message as "Number of choices exceded"

I'm using the code bellow:

```
def testParam = checkBox("modules", // name
                "", // values
                "", //default value
                15, //visible item cnt
                "Choose modules", // description
                )
```

I thought something like this for example:

```
when {
      expression {"$params.modules" // some function that works as count =>5}
}`enter code here`
steps {
        echo "Number of choices exceded"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is this `checkBox` method that you're mentioning?

Comment: Hi MaratC, it is referent to plugin extend choice parameter, I have multiples choices and multiselections, bellow some part of my code.

import com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition

    def checkBox (String name, String values, String defaultValue,
              int visibleItemCnt=15, String description='testando', String delimiter=',') {

    // default same as number of values
    visibleItemCnt = visibleItemCnt ?: values.split(',').size()
    return new ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition(

Comment: I have multiples choices and multiselections, I have more than 20 options to user choice, however I want limit just 5 choices though